# Docker image smaller after loading from .tar

Tags: docker

I have a large docker image that works on one server and i copied it to a different server using `docker save -o image_name.tar image_name:latest` and `cat docker_custom_image.tar | sudo docker import - image_name`.
The SHA256 checksum of the .tar file is the same after copying and the size of the files is the same. However after loading, the size of the image seen when running `docker images` is about 1/3 on the new serve compared to the original.
What could be the reason?

Trying to run `docker run image_name:latest "echo foo"`  results in:
`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "echo bla": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown` but i think this is a symptom of the image not being loaded properly.

Comment: I've only ever used `cat custom_docker_image.tar | docker load` to load image tar files.

Comment: Even better: `docker load -i custom_docker_image.tar`

Comment: So the issue i had with ```docker load``` was that it fails to load the image at all

Comment: The target machine had an older version of docker installed causing incompatability